# Search value in model object and if exists

Tags: python, django

I having a lot of problem with something I'm sure is pretty easy, but not for me.

I have 2 Models:

1. VipPassesModel
2. ProfileModel

Then I've this view, wich purpose is perform the following task (in this order):

1. Search if the "VIP Code" exists in the "VipPassesModel"
2. If "VIP Code" exists check if as some User (Profile Model - Foreing Key) asigned to it
3. If there's no user asigned to that VIP Code, then SAVE the current User logued (Id - Foreign Key) in that VIP Code (this will make this Vip Code no longer available)

**My VipPassesModel:**

```
class VipPassesModel(models.Model):
"""
VIP Passes Code Model.
"""

    code = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_asigned = models.ForeignKey(ProfileModel, related_name='profile_name', verbose_name="User Full Name", blank=True, null=True,)
```

**My View.py**

```
def vipcodevalidation(request):

"""
Funcion que recibe el CODE VIP y si es valido, lo asigna al usuario actual
"""
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = VipPassesForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            vipcode = form.cleaned_data['code']
            user_to_asign = request.user

            if VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode).exists():
            # Tomar el objeto y grabarle en "user_asigned" el id del usuario de django logueado actualmente (user_to_asign)

            else:
                    #nada que hacer aqui

    else:
        form = VipPassesForm()

    return render(request,'vipcode.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'll apreciate any help from you guys. Just to be clear, I'm not getting error messages, just I don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should be:

```
if VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode): #If there is object with that code
    vipObject = VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode)[0] # Get the object
    if not vipObject.user_assigned:  #If object doesn't have user
       vipObject.user_assigned = request.user.id  # Assign actual user
       vipObject.save()  # Save object
    else:
        #nada que hacer aqui
```

When you do `if VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode):`  if there is no objects, you get `[]`(empty list) so, if you do `if []` it returns false, because the list is empty, if there is one model with tat code, it returns the object like `[VipPassesModel]` so to access to it you need to do `VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode)[0]`

(*la documentación de Django oficial sobre este tipo de querys está bastante bien, te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a [Django Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)* )

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS!... You're the best... I need more friends like you.

This is the final View Code:

```
def vipcodevalidation(request):

"""
Funcion que recibe el CODE VIP y si es valido, lo asigna al usuario actual
"""
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = VipPassesForm(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        vipcode = form.cleaned_data['code']
        user_to_asign = request.user.id

        if VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode):
            vipObject = VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode)[0] # Get the object
            if not vipObject.user_asigned:  #If object doesn't have user
                vipObject.user_asigned = ProfileModel.objects.get(pk = user_to_asign)  # Assign actual user
                vipObject.save()  # Save object
                # VIP Code encontrado y User Asignado.
            else:
                # VIP Code encontrado pero ya tiene un User Asignado.
        else:
            #VIP Code no encontrado o ya tiene un User Asignado
else:
    form = VipPassesForm()

return render(request,'vipcode.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplistically this is what you can do

```
try:
    vipobj = VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode, user_asigned = NULL)[0]
except IndexError:
    #no vip code free to assign bail out

vipobj.user_assigned = user_to_asign
vipobj.save()
```

In real production level code, you should make these in a transaction sol that 2 requests from different user does not clash. 2nd request may override assignment by 1st request.

Comment: `.filter` doesn't fails if there is no object, there is no need to use `try except`

Comment: @Liarez, did you notice `[0]` to get the object?

Comment: Nope, I understand now why you use try except. Anyway you can do `if VipPassesModel.objects.filter(code = vipcode, user_asigned = NULL):` and if it is true, there will be an object for sure

Comment: `vipobj.user_assigned = user_to_asign` I supose this lines should be inside the `try`, if not, `vipobj` may no exists when you try to save it so your code will fail if the try fails

Comment: Yeah, I read it, but I didn't understand what you were trying to say. Sorry for my missunderstanding, but for me your code and comment are not clear at all, english is not my first language, I apologize for this